# Conversion from object to json text ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, ios7

What i need

```
 "sampleId":"[{\"TextVal\":\"10233\"}]"
```

Where i have

```
    NSDictionary *sampledict=@{@"TextVal": @"10233"};
    NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObject:sampledict];
    [dict setObject:arr forKey:@"sampleId"];
```

But converting this to json text gives me

```
   "sampleId":[{TextVal:10233}]
```

is there a way to get the value as `{\"TextVal\":\"10233\"}`?
This is for a web service call with POST data with following content.And the web service gives me Bad request error when excluding this \ .hence the requirement

Please note i am using `AFNetworking` for the purpose of network data fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like "nested JSON". You have to create JSON data for the array
`arr` first, and put that into the outer dictionary. Then create JSON data for the complete
object:

```
NSDictionary *sampledict = @{@"TextVal": @"10233"};
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sampledict];
NSData *innerJson = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *innerJsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:innerJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:innerJsonString forKey:@"sampleId"];

NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
```

Output:

```
{"sampleId":"[{\"TextVal\":\"10233\"}]"}
```

Comment: Brilliant..but what if i need     `sampleId = '[{\"TextVal\":\"10233\"}]';`

Comment: @LithuT.V: That does not look like valid JSON. JSON dictionaries are always of the form `{ key : value }`, using the colon `:` as separator, not `=`. And JSON strings are always enclosed in double quotation marks `"..."`, not `'...'`, compare http://json.org. Therefore I do not really understand this request.

Comment: Well in a rest client i need to input like this.but in code what explained in answer worked fine